# IllegalArgumentException: Mismatch in requested result type - but Type is set

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, entitymanager

I get following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Mismatch in requested result type [com.taqwaapps.entity.Event] and actual result type [com.taqwaapps.dto.EventDTO]
```

But my code points to the type I intent to receive:

```
@Repository
public class EventRepositoryImpl  {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<EventDTO> getLatestEventsFiltered(String sql, int limit) {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql, Event.class);
        query.setMaxResults(limit);

        List<EventDTO> resultList = (List<EventDTO>) query.getResultList();
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

Info: The objects `Event` and `EventDTO` are different.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql, Event.class);`  <---- Here you inform the library that it must parse the result using `Event.class`

But here `List<EventDTO> resultList = (List<EventDTO>) query.getResultList();` you try to parse the result using `EventDTO.class`

Change it into
`List<Event> resultList = query.getResultList();`

and then use some converter to convert the `List<Event>` into a `List<EventDTO>`

Comment: I had to change the object in first line to EventDTO . than it worked. in my sql code I am creating EventDTO directly through jpa constructor, so that works like I described.

Answer (score 2):

Before fixing your code you must be clear about the reasons for java.lang.IllegalArgumentException. [Refer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-solve-an-illegalargumentexception-in-java#:%7E:text=An%20IllegalArgumentException%20is%20thrown%20in,Java%20Virtual%20Machine%20(JVM).)

### Reasons for java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

- When Arguments out of range. For example, the percentage should lie between 1 to 100. If the user entered 101 then an IllegalArugmentExcpetion will be thrown.
- When argument format is invalid. For example, if our method requires date format like YYYY/MM/DD but if the user is passing YYYY-MM-DD. Then our method can’t understand then IllegalArugmentExcpetion will be thrown.
- When a method needs non-empty string as a parameter but the null string is passed.

Once you are clear about the issues, please refer to the solution which was already provided by @[Panagiotis Bougioukas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7237884/panagiotis-bougioukos)

### Issue - Argument format is invalid

### Most probably below solution should work(Not tested)

```
@Repository
public class EventRepositoryImpl {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<EventDTO> getLatestEventsFiltered(String sql, int limit) {

        var query = entityManager.createQuery(sql, Event.class);
        query.setMaxResults(limit);
        var resultList = query.getResultList().
                 stream().map(this::convertToDto).
                    collect(Collectors.toList());

        return resultList;
    }

    private EventDTO convertToDto(Event event) {
        var dto = new EventDTO();
        // convert event to eventdto here
        return dto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the long, informative answer!